# Hyperlink and Button_Click not working in Wix MBA

Tags: wix

I am new to Wix Toolset. I am using v3.6 and using ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost. 
In my theme .xml file, one of the pages looks like this -

```
  <Page Name="Install">
<Text X="11" Y="121" Width="400" Height="17" FontId="3">#(loc.InstallLicenseLabel)</Text>
<Hyperlink Name="eula" X="11" Y="138" Width="75" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="4" HoverFontId="4" SelectedFontId="4">#(loc.InstallLicenseTerms)</Hyperlink>
<Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="130" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallAcceptAndInstallButton)</Button>
<Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallDeclineButton)</Button></Page>
```

My problem is that I don't know where to add the reference source information for hyperlink. None of its attribute has this facility. Similarly, I am unable to associate event functions with buttons. Could any one please help me???

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN [article on Hypelink control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSI has an example:

```
<a href="http://www.blueyonderairlines.com">Blue Yonder Airlines</a>
```

So in WiX you would write something like:

```
<Hyperlink Name="eula"
           X="11" Y="138" Width="75" Height="17" TabStop="yes">
           &lt;a href=&quot;http://yoursite.com/&quot;&gt;Your Site&lt;/a&gt;
</Hyperlink>
```

You can also add some descriptive text to the control if you like.

---

Read [Control Your Controls](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/control-your-controls) section of WiX Tutorial to know how to add event handlers to buttons.

---

Windows Installer UI, and WiX correspondingly, is not very flexible. Yet it's enough for most installers.

Comment: I tried using this but anchor html appears instead of "Link description" and it still doesn't work. This is what I wrote <Hyperlink Name="eula" X="11" Y="138" Width="75" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="4" HoverFontId="4" SelectedFontId="4">&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt;#(loc.InstallLicenseTerms)&lt;/a&gt;</Hyperlink>

Comment: @VarunPandey So do you mean you see the contents of the `Hyperlink` element with the HTML formatting and no link at all?